# How long until my army men can produce metal?

Tags: metals, mining, manufacturing

After a bit of fighting, both green and tan team army men decide that they need more than plastic bullets to defeat each other, they want metal to make super armored metal tanks.

Green team sets up under a bush and gets a nice hidden area where they can fortify in secret and can easily dump unwanted dirt and stuff into a ditch nearby. Most of their energy can be put towards mining, but their space is limited under the bush so any heavy machines are pretty much a no go.

Tan team sets up a camp under the porch and has a lot of room to work. They can use big contraptions if needed, but are much more vulnerable to attacks. Half the troops are on guard and lookout, and until they get a foot down they lose about four hours a day to humans walking by and freezing them. They also have to spend time dragging excess dirt away so the humans don't get to curios about that giant dirt pile under the porch that just keeps growing bigger.

How long until Tan or Green team can start producing metal for their tanks?

More details-

- Green and Tan team can steal supplies from indoors if they are needed for ceiling braces or machines or whatever.
- Assume they have shovels, wheelbarrows, picks, and misc hand tools when they start digging.
- They will first spend a few days fortifying before they start mining. Green will probably take two days, Tan a week.
- They know how to refine/produce/whatever to get good metal for their armored tanks.
- Precious metals mean nothing if they aren't good for their tanks(gold is worthless to them).
- Assume they won't be attacked at least for the next month.
- some more details on [this question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/188308/how-would-randomly-interacting-humans-change-the-battle-strategies-of-2-inch-tal).
- For the sake of a good story, they'll start finding metals about three feet down.
- More available on request if needed.

Comment: *"They'll start finding metals about three feet down":* no they won't, unless by "metals" you mean gold, or the copper or aluminium inside electric power cables. Otherwise, what they may find is *ore*, which is basically some special sort of not-metal dirt or rock which can be *smelted* into metal.

Comment: How much wood can a woodchuck chuck if a woodchuck could chuck wood? He would chuck all the wood that a woodchuck could chuck if a woodchuck could chuck wood. Ignoring the fact that (a) plastic has a lower melting point than metal, (b) it would be easier to steal metal objects from the house, (c) they have picks and shovels and could melt those down first... we also have (d) no idea how fast a plastic figure with a bound base can move or leverage weight, (e) the plastic would break before the job was done... You need to pick a (large) number and move forward.

Comment: I agree with JBH. This question is primarily opinion-based and is a bit unclear.

Comment: @JBH, humans also has lower melting point than metal.

Comment: @ksbes True, but humans have a lot of biology used for regulating and removing heat (blood flow, sweat, etc). We can survive metallurgy. When we get hot, we don't get soft and pliable.

Comment: Who needs tanks? Raid the old fellow next door who has a couple magnifying glasses, and draw the enemy into a Heat Ray ambush on the next sunny day. Also, at two inches, [Antlions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antlion), larger spiders, and other common predators are significant threats to the force.

Answer (score 1):

I want to mention that gold is not worthless - it is a perfect bullet material! And stability physics works a little bit difernt at small scales. That cubic-square law, you know. It means that even tincan armor can be ultimate for such sizies/speeds.

So your litle soldires can immediatly:

- collect all metall litter and tools (tincans, scissors - this are super ultimate for armor, shaving blades, coins, etc.)
- start to make bullets from gold, lead and solder with soldering-iron
- use gold, lead and solder as a soldering material to craft metal contaptions of their choise.
- if they can steal some gas burner (their owners must be great DIY fans) they can even bend, cut and weld steel

They can begin it all at first night. Local home apocalipsis is enevatable!